# 'In call' expanded status header on iPhone shifts some views, but not others (uiscrollview)

Tags: iphone, ios

While in a phone call, if you navigate to our app, you will see a bit of a 'mess'.  Because the top status view doubles in size to indicate the presence of a phone call and allow quick switching back to the phone interface, the rest of the screen is shifted down.

For some reason, 2 of our views are not shifted with the rest.  It may be coincidence, but they are both UIScrollViews.

Is there a setting that needs to be checked for a view to shift accordingly due to system events like the expanded call notifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolve by adjusting the struts in IB to reference the top of the screen.